# VBA obtaining filename of last file in a directory

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to obtain the filename of the file that's in last place in a directory.

For example directory 'x' contains files:

1001

1002

1003

1004

I want to obtain the name of file 1004 so I can use it in a messagebox like this:

`MsgBox("The last file is: " & FileName)`

And the messagebox shows: 'The last file is 1004'.

Anyone who knows how I can achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean by the last file? Get all the file names in an array and sort them as you like: by filename, by creation date, by modification date etc...

Comment: The directory sorts the files on name, with the highest number at the bottom. I want the file with the highest number, the file that's all the way at the bottom of the directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Function GetLastFile(ByVal folder As String) As String

    Dim cmdOutput As String

    '// Make sure folder has trailing "\" 
    If Right$(folder, 1) <> Application.PathSeparator Then
        folder = folder & Application.PathSeparator
    End If

    '// Use command prompt to get a directory listing, sorted in Z-A order and read all the output into a string variable
    cmdOutput = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec("CMD /C DIR """ & folder & "*.*"" /A:-D /B /O:-N").StdOut.ReadAll

    '// Get the first line from the output
    GetLastFile = CStr(Split(cmdOutput, vbCrLf)(0))

End Function
```

example use:

```
MsgBox "Last file in folder is: " & GetLastFile("C:\Documents\BloggsJ\")
```

Comment: Do I need to modify anything other than `GetLastFile("C:\Documents\BloggsJ\")` to the right folder?

Comment: Nope, just change the path to the folder that you want to search in.

Comment: It opens 'C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\CMD.exe' then does nothing. When I press close the messagebox shows up with 'Last file in folder is: Microsoft Windows [Version xxxxx]'. What's going wrong here?

Comment: @Stan I missed a flag in the parameters - see edit above and try that

Comment: @SierraOscar   How could I modify this so it only looks for files begining with the two letters CP  ?  When I run it as is, it returns some file name thumbs.db which I don't even see in the folder.

Comment: @ORLANDOVAZQUEZ change `*.*` to `CP.*`